# How do I loop through two lists and extract the elements from the first list if element in second list is present?

Tags: python, list

There are two lists which contain the following:

```
list1 = ['This egg is delicious', 'I love blueberry waffles', 'Eating blueberry waffles has always been my favorite', 'I recommend the pork belly', 'Chocolate Sundae hits the spot'] 

list2 = ['egg','Chocolate Sundae']
```

I would like the outcome to be something like this. As you can see, list2 has the words and I would like for it to loop through and extract elements from list1 only because it has the words from list2. How do I go about achieving this?

```
['This egg is delicious','Chocolate Sundae hits the spot']
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I did try a poorly made for loop something like this 
`for i in list1:
for k in list2:`

I do not know how to move on from there

Comment: @Putt-Putt please show it, we can then fix your error

Comment: You may need regex. The problem is you are looking for multiple word combinations with variable number of words.

Comment: @mahir I just did two for loop as mentioned above. However, I do not know how to move on from there.

Comment: add whatever you have , then we will complete that for you

Comment: @Putt-Putt Do you want to match `'Chocolate Sundae hits the spot'` beacause it has exact 'Chocolate Sundae' or because it has 'Chocolate **OR** 'Sundae'?

Answer (score 1):

```
list3 =[]

for i in list1:
  for k in list2:
    if k in i:
      list3.append(i)

print(list3)
```

Comment: according to me you need to remove the repeated elements that you could get

Comment: hmm.. the question doesn't speak about duplicates. if that is the case, the list can be converted into python set and again the set object can be converted into list...

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex. `re.search`

**Ex:**

```
import re
list1 = ['This egg is delicious', 'I love blueberry waffles', 'Eating blueberry waffles has always been my favorite', 'I recommend the pork belly', 'Chocolate Sundae hits the spot']
list2 = ['egg','Chocolate Sundae']

checkVal = "|".join(list2)
print([i for i in list1 if re.search(checkVal, i)])
```

**Output:**

```
['This egg is delicious', 'Chocolate Sundae hits the spot']
```